# PHP failing with Out of Memory: Kill process - is it possible for me to make loops more efficient?

Tags: php, linux-kernel

My php is running out of memory with a server error "Out of memory:Kill process..about 25% of the way through the process"  Although it searches through about 10,000 lines, the number of lines that match the criteria, and therefore need to be stored and written to the file at the end of the process, are less than 200.  So I am not sure why it is running out of memory.

Am I receiving this error because I am not clearing variables after each loop, or do I need to increase the memory on the server?

The process in brief is:
 - LOOPA - loop through list of 400 zip codes
 - using one api call for each zip - get list of all places within each zip (typically about 40-50)

-- SUBLOOP1 - for each place found, use an api call to get all events for that place

---- SUBLOOP1A loop through events to count the number for each place

```
zips = file($configFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$dnis = file($dniFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$s3->registerStreamWrapper();
$file = fopen("s3://{$bucket}/{$key}", 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($file, $type . " id" . "\t" . $type . " name" . "\t" . "zip" . "\t" . "event count" . "\n" );

foreach($zips as $n => $zip){
    //first line is the lable to describe zips, so skip it
    if ($n < 1) continue;
    $params = $url;
    $params .= "&q=" . $zip;

    $more_node_pages = true;
    while ($more_node_pages){
    $res = fetchEvents($params);

        //Now find the number of events for each place
        foreach($res->data as $node){
            //first check if on Do Not Include list
            $countevents = true;
            foreach($dnis as $dni) {
                if ($dni == $node->id) {
                    echo "Not going to get events for ". $node->name . "   id# " . $dni . "\n\n";
                    $countevents = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if it found a match, skip this and go to the next
            if (!$countevents) continue;
            $params = $url . $node->id . "/events/?fields=start_time.order(reverse_chronological)&limit=" . $limit . "&access_token=". $access_token; 

            //Count the number of valid upcoming events for that node
            $event_count = 0;
            $more_pages = true;
            $more_events = true;

            while ($more_pages) {

                $evResponse = fetchEvents($params);
                if (!empty($evResponse->error)) {
                    checkError($evResponse->error->message, $evResponse->error->code, $file);
                } 

                //if it finds any events for that place, go throught each event for that place one by one to count until you reach today
                foreach($evResponse->data as $event){
                    if(strtotime($event->start_time) > strtotime('now')){
                        $event_count++;
                    }
                    //else we have reached today's events for this node, so get out of this loop, and don't retrieve any more events for this node
                    else {
                        $more_events = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($evResponse->paging->next) and $more_events) $params = $evResponse->paging->next;
                else $more_pages = false;
            } //end while loop looking for more pages with more events for that node (page)

            if ($event_count > "0") {
                fwrite($file, $node->id . "\t" . $node->name . "\t" . $zip . "\t" . $event_count . "\n");
                echo $event_count . "\n";
            }
        } // loop back to the next place until done
        //test to see if there is an additional page
        if (!empty($res->paging->next)) $params = $res->paging->next; else $more_node_pages = false;
    } //close while loop for $more_node_pages containing additional nodes for that zip
} // loop back to the next zip until done
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend adding output to the beginning of each nested loop. I think you most likely have an infinite loop, which is causing the script to run out of memory.

If that isn't the case, then you can try increasing the memory limit for your PHP script by adding this line of PHP to the top of your script:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "5G");
```

If it takes more than 5GB of RAM for your script to process the 400 zip codes, I would recommend breaking your script up so that you can run zip codes 0-10 and then 11-20, then 21-30, etc.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thank you, but it is definitely not an infinite loop, because if I only use 5 zip codes, it works like a charm. I can increase the memory limit, but I am concerned that is masking a larger issue, since I don't see how the memory could be that excessive.

Comment: This did solve the problem. Even though memory_get_usage() was consistently under the limit, there must have been something it was not counting. Thanks!

Comment: I have found that (especially with PHP7 pthreads) the only 'reliable" source of memory usage is a cli tool like top, htop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out where the memory is being lost and then you can either take care of it or work around it. `memory_get_usage()` is your friend - print it at the top (or bottom) of each loop with some identifier so you can see when & where you are using up memory.

Comment: I did put in the "memory_get_usage", and the peak variable, and it never increases. it is always at 3.75MB. if the php memory used is excessive, would that cause a kernel OOM error as described above?